# Can I make a video not downloadable?

Tags: internet, video-streaming

I'm a user who has Internet Download Manager and I haven't met any video content that couldn't be downloaded by IDM.

Now I would place some videos on my website and make them not downloadable, or at least not viewed after downloaded – and I'd like to make impossible to change the format of content into a viewable one. I want to use it for info-business.

How can I do that?

P.S. I do not consider Screen Recording as a problem, as I know they decrease quality of videos. Am I right?

Comment: If it's viewable, it's downloadable.

Comment: @Ignacio I'm not talking about screening it. Maybe there's any  solution?  Or at least HARD DOWNLOADABLE

Comment: This is why Netflix is trying so hard to get DRM in HTML5 btw: http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/04/html5-video-at-netflix.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - even more: viewing **requires** downloading, which **equals** copying.

Comment: A common solution to this problem is to always be generating new and interesting content about a subject that changes frequently or constantly. If you are providing access to video content that becomes mostly obsolete within a short time (months or at most a few years) after you provide it, people are more inspired to pay a subscription to access the latest content when you make it available.

Comment: Another solution is to produce video content that is of insufficient quality to be of interest to those that might want to share it, however it is marketed well and has the right price, so that those making the purchase decision are more likely to subscribe. I can think of one vendor that does this, and I'm not sure that it is intentional. This is a poor strategy, though, obviously.

Comment: Yes, you can make your video not downloadable; don't put it on your website.

Comment: Define difference between "download" and "frames appear one by one on my computer's frame buffer".

Comment: @Kaz that wouldn't be a great idea; I don't think video compression works like that exactly.  (I mean, unless we're talking *uncompressed* --- but then you've got a different set of problems.)

Comment: Linking all _view-but-no-copy_ questions together: http://superuser.com/questions/391876/can-i-encrypt-data-in-a-way-that-it-can-be-read-normally-but-cant-be-copied-or http://superuser.com/questions/404712/copy-proof-flash-drive

Comment: Some TV station catch-up services (like ABC Australia) encrypt the content which only their flash player can decode. 

http://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/kb/protect-video-content-flash-media.html

This makes it harder to download, but there's still lots of tools that can apparently download and decrypt the content.

Comment: Why don't you add a watermark on the videos? Thus turning the problem into a benefit. Yes watermarks can be removed, but most people won't bother.

Comment: Beyond the fact that playing = downloading, there'd be nothing stopping someone from running a screen recorder while playing it in fullscreen.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This this this this this this this. People everywhere really need to understand this most basic of computing concepts. Judges, lawmakers, lawyers, and companies, especially so. **If and only if your content is downloadable is it viewable!**

Comment: "I want to use it for info-business." What does this mean? Why exactly do you want to stop people from "downloading" your videos?

Comment: @Burhan, info business is a kind of business when you sell your information or knowledge. and  i don't want my videos get free and be uploaded to free video sources like Youtube.

Comment: @Izkata, I do not consider video screening as a problem. The worse part is when a video is easily downloadable by simple programs teenagers use.

Comment: @Nightwolf, I do not know about watermarks. I'll look for that.

Comment: @Gio, Basically it is a logo over the video advertising your business. All you have to consider is not charging to view the video's but gain profit in some other means. Example advertising and minor fees for no advertising at all.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It is impossible to show the user a video in a browser without them also having the ability to download and keep it. If there was a way to do so then every video site would be doing it.

There are a bunch of tricks you can do to make it much more difficult such as only allowing the video file to be requested within X seconds of the page loading with some clever server-side logic - but these are just minor roadblocks.

To attempt is futile.

Comment: What if I give a link to download a zip archive with the videos inside, and take money for this,is it possible to let watch but not upload them somewhere? maybe its better to write my own program with video inside, and make people install my prog on only one computer and not let them install on others? like an usual key system for antiviruses-I use the key> install the program> view the content until i have right for it. and let the program stream the video from my server. how's the idea?

Comment: @Gio If you give the users a ZIP file, they can do whatever they want with it. Going the route of giving users a program to watch videos and restrict them to a key sounds like a bad idea—basically this is what all copyright protection systems tried and utterly failed with, because either the program wasn't secured well enough or people stopped using it because it was awkward to work with. If you do that, you'll just annoy the customers who paid for your content in good faith.

Comment: @slhck there are some websites that make me download special software to download my wanted program. what if i make people download the program to watch the videos in the same way?

Comment: @Gio Your best option would be streaming the video.  But you need to remember, if the video is viewable to the end user, there is always a possibility for them to copy it in some way.  There is no way around it.  If the video is displayed on their computer, at the very least they can run a video capture program will its playing.

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate here: Hardware decoder and encrypted file - does this not work? Pay for the decoder, distribute encoded files. You'd basically have to reroute the decoders output, which, I believe, would fall under HARD DOWNLOADABLE

Comment: @Gio - A number of places that distribute video clients are disseminating _malicious_ ones; that is, the programs (if they read a video stream at all) install malware/rootkits on the computer.  And if you do distribute your own, you have to make sure that it's hardened against malicious streams...

Comment: @AK4749: Well - the user have to have the decoder in the first place (which is probably unlikely because you would severely limit the userbase - and since no stream is using it no one have the initiative to buy one) AND the decoder outputs only to trusted source (the connection to monitor would need to be encoded.

Comment: @AK4749 That's [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and it doesn't work. *Everything* can be reverse engineered(an example is the [CCS system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System)).

Comment: @AK4749 There's dozens of free screen recorders.  If it's visible on the monitor, it's re-recordable.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka completely makes sense. I guess what I just can't wrap my head around is the fact that with higher-bit encryption, there is no (feasible) way to break, say, a banking transaction. Why is this not true for DRM? Is it solely because the end user that must provide an authentication also has the malicious intent of re-appropriating the content? I would imagine that cryptanalysis would have studied multiparty key distribution by now. Is that a thing? Thank you for your responses guys

Comment: With banking transactions you're still not trying to hide anything from a user, just move the data around safely. You could move a video file around safely, but you can't stop the receiver from just keeping a copy of the unencrypted version (or just using screen capture software)

Comment: @Izkata: it's not that linear, if you're talking about *software* screen recorders. Since Windows Vista, there's [Protected Media Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Media_Path) which ensures (barring kernel-level cracks) that the video can't be intercepted by other software or displayed on non-HDCP-enabled devices. Of course, there's always the analog hole, but that requires recording *hardware*.

Answer (score 20):

As PhonicUK said: if your browser shows something, a user will always have the possibility to store that information somewhere. You'll never be safe, unless you implement some kind of encryption, but you wouldn't want to do this yourself. If you offer the video files for download, even worse. When a client has a file to store on their computer, it's completely up to them what they want to do with it. They can copy it to other devices, upload it online, etc.

And this is not a bad thing. Whenever you try making it harder to rip a video, you make it harder for regular paying customers to get and use the content as well. This is, in essence, annoying. Several companies have tried to enforce copyright schemes upon users and majorly screwed it up. For example, there was a time where CDs were only playable on a computer by launching a [separate clunky piece of <s>software</s> rootkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_Sony_BMG_CD_copy_protection_scandal). Needless to say no honest paying customer liked that. Music distribution services like iTunes used to sell DRM-protected files, but later [decided to ditch that](http://www.macworld.com/article/1138000/drm_faq.html).

Making your customers happier could make them recommend your services, and not shoving a complicated and customized copyright protection (like supplying the files in an application that decrypts them) will make you stand out as the good guy.  So far, almost every protection was broken at some point anyway. Your business really should not rely on the content alone, but on the satisfaction of the customers primarily.

Now, for businesses that depend on monetization of their content, and where piracy would cause major loss (if there's a way to measure that is debatable), there *are* streaming services that specialize on content distribution with proper access right management and content protection. [Brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com/) is one of those services:

> Protect your valuable contentEnsure your video is safe. Use RTMPe stream encryption and SWF verification to prevent video stream ripping and content theft and ensure that your video stream plays back only in your authorized players.

There are similar services, who mostly partner with broadcasting institutions (TV channels, etc.), but note that if you decide to go that route, you will have to pay for the service. These services don't work miracles though. If you can view something on your computer you can easily run a desktop recording software and capture it to a file. If the file's been viewed in the browser it was cached somewhere as well. So, in essence, expect your customers to play nice, and play it nice yourself.

Comment: The only time I wasn't able to capture a video stream normally was when a family member was interviewed by a local TV station for winning an athletic event.  After a few futile hours chasing a working tool to break their protection mechanism I did an end run with a screen grabber and just kept it at a high file size to minimize multiple compression artifacts.

Comment: @slhck♦ i have checked the Brightcover. I was waiting a protection that can make video undownloadable , before it will be allowed to watch. The thing I got from this experiment was the next>>> I have downloaded the video they were protecting, using IDM (Internet Download Manager) and the protection didn't work . So maybe there's no way to protect content?

Comment: @Gio "Making something undownloadable before being able to watch" does not make sense really. If you're watching it, you're downloading it. There's never a fully safe way to protect content, no.

Answer (score 10):

If a user can see the video in his computer, the video is, somehow, *downloaded* to his computer, so that his computer can process it and show it.

If it is downloaded, then, well... it is downloaded. Very basic and very complicated at the same time: doesn't matter if you allow the person to see it in the web, or require him to use a special program, or to use a special key... at some point, the program is run, the key is used, and the original video is displayed in the screen. Even HDMI devices, that should have some special hardware allowing to encrypt/decrypt the video, were already hacked.

And you can't prevent the user from using a camcord to record the video from his monitor.

If all your business relly upon this, something is wrong or something will go wrong.

Comment: This is the fundamental answer. On the internet, view or play = download = copy. I can't see it unless the data gets from your site to my computer and my computer has a copy.

Answer (score 8):

Even if you take the considerable effort develop your own video player plugin, which performs a session key exchange with your server and receives the video stream encrypted with a session key, attackers will simply take the path of least resistance: the playback hole. The playback hole means that a video can be duplicated by using a program which grabs the decoded frames from the frame buffer while the video is playing, while simultaneously capturing the audio by tapping into the operating system's audio framework.

You have to ask yourself: **if the video is freely viewable, what's wrong if someone wants to stash away a copy**? The only consequence is that people can share the video and not visit your site.
But you can put notices in your video which lead people back to the source. So it's ultimately a good thing. People are copying **your** video and seeing your message. *You have duped people into letting you use their private storage devices to host your video!* :)

If you somehow succeed in making a video very hard to copy, then it will be only copied by hard-core crackers. Hard-core crackers will not be satisfied with merely sharing the cracked video. They will want credit for cracking it, so they will deface your video with their own messages, perhaps removing or overwriting some of your visual or audio content.

If your video is easy to download and copy, then it will be your original, unaltered video in its original quality that people are sharing.

Answer (score 4):

This can't be done. It's analogous to mandating that a magazine you've mailed to a subscriber is shredded after they read it.

In order for the user's computer to show them the video, the computer needs to know what to show them. This requires the server to send the content to the user's computer. While there are systems of video delivery that can prevent the common user from saving a streaming video, the fact that you have to actually send the content of the video to them in the first place means you can't prevent them from getting the video.

Videos can be encoded in various different ways (mp4, avi, mov, etc). The important thing to remember here is that the encoding is not there to *prevent people from viewing the content*, but to *enable people to view it* by defining how the data should be converted to picture and sound. In order for a user to watch a video at all, they need both the data making up the video and some tool to show that to them as a video. There is no way around that. Take away the data, there is no video to watch. Take away the method to transform it into something meaningful, and the data is just junk that can't be watched.

---

The bottom line is this:

- If your video can be watched, it can be downloaded.
- If your video can't be downloaded, it can't be watched.

Answer (score 3):

The answers saying this cannot be done are rather native and misleading. Sure, no security system is theoretically foolproof. However, **there are technologies in widespread use that can indeed make it nearly impossible to steal a video, while still allowing it to be viewed. These are called DRM technologies and are used by all the major premium content providers (e.g. Netflix, Hulu).**

DRM works by encrypting the video and requiring a secure player component in order to decrypt it and play it back. The player component is hardened against tampering - for example, if a hacker attempts to break into it, the player does it best to detect this and shuts itself down as soon as it detects an attack.

Likewide, the player validates all the connected devices and stops playback if e.g. you connect a DVD recorder to your PC. You can configure it to only allow playback on devices that verify that they are not recorders. Most modern monitors implement HDCP, which - among other features - ensures that content cannot be stolen even by tapping the monitor cable.

Make no mistake - such a protected video can still be stolen by skilled experts. However, it will prevent theft by almost all normal users. Even the user somehow manages to download the video file (e.g. using Internet Download Manager), he cannot do anything useful with it because it is encrypted. Only a skilled hacker can obtain the encryption key.

This type of protection is required by all premium content providers (movie studios) and quite widespread. I work with the Microsoft **PlayReady** technology, which seems to be the most popular DRM technology in widespread use.

My employer provides the [SilverHD DRM](http://axinom.com/PlayReady) service, which enables you to protect your videos with PlayReady and present them on all modern platforms, for a small monthly fee. Playback on mobile platforms is currently more expensive, due to the need to license a player component for them (**Microsoft provides free players for their own platforms, including Silverlight in any modern PC/Mac browser**). If you are interested in a commercial solution, feel free to get in touch via the link on the website.

For a demonstration, please see the [Video Paradise sample website](http://videoparadise.silverhd.net). I guarantee that you cannot steal these movies without major effort.

Comment: please, can you give me a link of website that has DRM service. I'm still sure that any content can be downloaded :( I leave in Republic of Georgia and some videos can't be opened. I'm limited in checking the protection, but as I said before , I have checked one; I entered to a website which was protected by http://www.brightcove.com/ service, videos were not free, and to view the video content you should have payed for it. I tried to check. When I clicked on a video with a cost of 1.99$ it was not streaming, but a trial program I have installed (IDM) already was ready to download the video...

Comment: *Make no mistake - such a protected video can still be stolen by skilled experts. However, it will prevent theft by almost all normal users.* -- Of course, normal users will just go to http://thepiratebay.sx and get a copy made available by the skilled experts.

Comment: @Gio - sample website link added to answer.

Comment: I think the naïve and misleading answer is this one. The other answers are well aware of the existence of DRM technology and have given excellent explanations of why it doesn't (and cannot) work. By the way, the 'major effort' in my case was three and a half minutes and that included me writing this comment.

Comment: @Sander, I saw this link, updated plugin (silverlight) and couldn't watch the download  video /* I'm glad for that*/ . Could you suggest me how and where can i see instruction and service to get the same protection on my videos (is the price high?)

Comment: @Gio - please contact info@axinom.com to get more info about the SilverHD DRM service. The price is not very high in my opinion (cannot discuss details in public forum).

Comment: @MarcksThomas - do you mean you managed to break PlayReady in three and a half minutes? I would be very interested in learning more about that - please elaborate.

Comment: For the user to view it streamed, either (a) it has to be sent unencrypted, or (b) you have to give them the key. Encryption does not prevent a user allowed to watch the video from downloading it.

Comment: Quite right - the key needs to be delivered to the player one way or another. Protecting the key from being stolen is one of the main design principles of the DRM system - generally this is done by attempting to make sure that only the secure component in the player has access to the key (encrypting it in transit and making it hard to discover in memory). Breaking the player and extracting the key is the primary attack vector that has been used against DRM in the past.

Comment: "making it hard to discover" == security by obscurity (i.e., worthless).